# Push specific row values to result array if row column value matches search string

Tags: php, arrays, key

I have an array with a lot of different `$key`s and `$value`s
What I did is create a form that allows the user to insert an emailadres.
Then a `foreach` loop start running and saves the values of every found emailaddress to a new `array`

This is the outcome of that array:

```
<?php 
Array
(
    [0] => email@email.com
    [1] => 103646
    [2] => Company
    [3] => 1140
    [4] => email@email.com
    [5] => 103689
    [6] => Company
    [7] => 3400
)
?>
```

What I would like it that every `$value` has it's own `$key`

I don't really know how to accomplish that.

This is my array making script:

```
<?php
$saved = array();
$input = $_GET['emailaddress'];
foreach ($data as $files){
    $bedrijf = $files['Name'];
    $bill = $files['Bill'];
    $amount = $files['Amount'];
    $email = $files['email'];
    if ($email == $input){
        foreach($files as $values){
            $saved[] = $values;
        }

    }
}
echo'<pre>';
print_r($saved);
echo'</pre>';
?>
```

Comment: own key in the sense? can you give an example?

Comment: how does your `$data` look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that by one foreach. No need to increase complexity of the code.

```
$i = 0;
foreach ($data as $files){
    $bedrijf = $files['Name'];
    $bill = $files['Bill'];
    $amount = $files['Amount'];
    $email = $files['email'];
    if ($email == $input){
            $saved[$i]['email'] = $email;
            $saved[$i]['Amount'] = $amount;
            $saved[$i]['bill '] = $bill;    
            $saved[$i]['Name'] = $bedrijf ;    
            $i++;
    }
}
```

Comment: I just provide a solution which might also work And if you want same keys then you need to create multi-dim array.

Answer (score 2):

This will provide the desired multi-dimensional associative array without the code bloat of manually incrementing indexes or declaring one-time-use variables:

```
foreach ($data as $files) {
    if ($files['email'] === $input) {
        $saved[] = [
            'Email' => $files['email'],
            'Amount' => $files['Amount'],
            'Bill' => $files['Bill'],
            'Name' => $files['Name']
        ];
    }
}
```